# Flask sqlalchemy many-to-many insert data

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a many to many relation here in **Flask-SQLAlchemy**, but it seems that I don't know how to fill the *"many to many identifier database"*. Could you please help me understand what I am doing wrong and how it is supposed to look?

```python
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_fistName = db.Column(db.String(64))
    user_lastName = db.Column(db.String(64))
    user_email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)


class Class(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'classes'
    class_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    class_name = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
```

and then my identifier database:

```
student_identifier = db.Table('student_identifier',
    db.Column('class_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('classes.class_id')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
)
```

so far it looks like this when I try to insert the data into the database.

```
# User
user1 = User(
            user_fistName='John',
            user_lastName='Doe',
            user_email='john@doe.es')

user2 = User(
            user_fistName='Jack',
            user_lastName='Doe',
            user_email='jack@doe.es')

user3 = User(
            user_fistName='Jane',
            user_lastName='Doe',
            user_email='jane@doe.es')

db.session.add_all([user1, user2, user3])
db.session.commit()

# Class
cl1 = Class(class_name='0A')
cl2 = Class(class_name='0B')
cl3 = Class(class_name='0C')
cl4 = Class(class_name='Math')
cl5 = Class(class_name='Spanish')
db.session.add_all([cl1, cl2, cl3, cl4, cl5])
db.session.commit()
```

Now my problem is, how do I add to the many to many database, since I really can't create a 'student_identifier' object? If I could it could perhaps have looked like this:

```
# Student Identifier
sti1  = StiClass(class_id=cl1.class_id, class_name=user1.user_id)
sti2  = StiClass(class_id=cl3.class_id, class_name=user1.user_id)
sti3  = StiClass(class_id=cl4.class_id, class_name=user1.user_id)
sti4  = StiClass(class_id=cl2.class_id, class_name=user2.user_id)
db.session.add_all([sti1, sti2, sti3, sti4])
db.session.commit()
```

How I am supposed to insert into a many to many table with ORM?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You don't need to add anything directly to your association table, SQLAlchemy will do that. This is more or less from [SQLAlchemy documentations](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many):

```
association_table = db.Table('association', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('left_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('left.id')),
    db.Column('right_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('right.id'))
)

class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = db.relationship("Child",
                    secondary=association_table)

class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


p = Parent()
c = Child()
p.children.append(c)
db.session.add(p)
db.session.commit()
```

Therefore your sample would be like this:

```
student_identifier = db.Table('student_identifier',
    db.Column('class_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('classes.class_id')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.user_id'))
)

class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_fistName = db.Column(db.String(64))
    user_lastName = db.Column(db.String(64))
    user_email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)


class Class(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'classes'
    class_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    class_name = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    students = db.relationship("Student",
                               secondary=student_identifier)

s = Student()
c = Class()
c.students.append(s)
db.session.add(c)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Let's say my students already exist in a table. How do I append them to a class without having to query the whole data for each student each time (using foreing key only)?

Comment: @axwell, If you often require students for Class (i.e. when check on update), you could tune relationship with lazy='subquery' like this:

`students = db.relationship("Student",
                                          secondary=student_identifier,
                                          lazy='subquery',
                                          backref=db.backref('classes', lazy=True))`

Comment: @axwell You can also do the insertion like this if the student already exist:


`session.execute(
            student_identifier.insert(),
            params={"class_id": class_id, "user_id": user_id},
        )`

Comment: how can we access student_identifier table(in this case) from repository

Answer (score 25):

First off, `student_identifier` is defined as a SQLAlchemy reflection table not a database.

Normally if you have all the relationship setup properly between models and reflection table objects, you will only need to deal with related models (by appending model objects into the relationship InstrumentList) in order to insert data into reflection tables, for instance, the answer @mehdi-sadeghi provided above.

However, there is indeed a way to insert directly into reflection tables if you don't want to setup the relationship. For example:

```
statement = student_identifier.insert().values(class_id=cl1.id, user_id=sti1.id)
db.session.execute(statement)
db.session.commit()
```

After that, you should be able to see that a many-to-many relationship row is inserted into the `student_identifier` reflection table. Don't forget to commit after you execute each SQL statement as it's done in a transaction.

Hope that helps you with an alternative approach.

Comment: how can I import this reflection table or association table?

Comment: @jibinmathew just as you would with classes and other symbols.

Comment: @jibinmathew I also have a problem when import the association table, so I import the table locally, exactly at the above where I calling that.

Comment: @GofyandKitty that could be an indicator on circular dependency/import in your code base so that you need to use local import (to provide namespace) in order to make it work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this solution. You literally saved me

Comment: This is awesome! Is there something similar but to delete an association?

Comment: This ignores the check for duplicates

Answer (score 4):

To extend cowgills answer, you can also add multiple entries at once using `extend`:

```
class_ = db.session.query(Class).first()
new_students = db.session.query(Student).all()
class_.students.extend(new_students)
db.session.add(class_)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: I need to reassign all the students. How do I reset the students before extending it? Simply with `class_.students = []` and then extend it?

Comment: I think there is no need to `class_.students = []`. Simply `class_.students=new_students` should override existing relations.

Comment: I see, thank you. But what about the existing ones? I am removing them explicitly now, but what if I do not? would the ORM do it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this on my models

```py
show = db.Table('Show',
  db.Column('artist_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artists.id'), primary_key = True),
  db.Column('venue_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('venues.id'), primary_key = True),
  db.Column('start_time',db.DateTime, nullable = False )
)
```

```py
class Venue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'venues'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    genres = db.Column(db.String())
    website_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    seeking_talent = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable = False, default= False)
    seeking_description = db.Column(db.String())
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    
    def __repr__(self):
            return f'<Venue ID: {self.id}, Name: {self.name}>'
```

```py
class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'artists'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    genres = db.Column(db.String())
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    website_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    seeking_venue = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable = False, default= False)
    seeking_description = db.Column(db.String())
    venues = db.relationship('Venue', secondary = show, backref = db.backref('artists', lazy = True))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
            return f'<Artist ID: {self.id}, Name: {self.name}>'
```

And I performed the insertion as follows in my app.py (Inserting into the association table)

```py
 new_show = show.insert().values(
        artist_id = form.artist_id.data,
        venue_id = form.venue_id.data ,
        start_time = form.start_time.data
         )
      db.session.execute(new_show)
      db.session.commit()
```