# Flask sqlalchemy many-to-many update data

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

Similar to [this question on insert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25668092/248616).

I wonder how we do update for a many-to-many relation using flask-sqlalchemy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask sqlalchemy many-to-many insert data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668092/flask-sqlalchemy-many-to-many-insert-data)

Comment: It is the same ^^