# Flask Adding multiple tags from a form to the database

Tags: python, flask

What is the database logic for adding a post with tags? The current relationship has a many-to-many association table, but I am unsure how to create the logic to add tags to the database.

My models looks like:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} {}>'.format(self.id, self.title[:20])


class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime(), server_default=func.now())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{}:{}>".format(self.id, self.name)


post_tags = db.Table('post_tags',
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id')),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'))
)
```

Currently, my view logic is set to only add the posts, but I would like to add the functionality so that it adds the tags as well, If I add a tag database insert like below,

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    body = form.body.data
    tags = form.tags.data
    post = Post(body=body, user_id=current_user.id)
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    if tags:
        new_tag = Tag(name=tags, slug=tags)
        db.session.add(new_tag)
        db.session.commit()
```

The above logic when I test it out, it appears to treat the tags and the post database inserts as if they are separate entities.

Also, how do I handle added multiple tags to the database? For example, if I have a form and the tags are all comma separated how do I add each tag?

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216874/flask-sqlalchemy-many-to-many-insert