# sqlalchemy many to many association table not inserting rows

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

Writing my first web app using flask / SQLAlchemy.  I have a many to many relationship between 'persons' and 'facilities.'  When I successfully add a person using the registration form, the association table does not get a row added.  Do I have to insert that row manually?

Here is the pertinent part of the model:

```
# app/models.py

from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

from app import db, login_manager

# [START model]

# Build secondary table for many to many between facilities and persons
workers = db.Table('workers',
    db.Column('facility_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('facilities.id')),
    db.Column('person_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('persons.id'))
)


class Facility(db.Model):
    __tablename__='facilities'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60))
    description = db.Column(db.String(128))
    persons = db.relationship('Person', secondary='workers', backref='facilities', lazy = 'dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Facility name='%s')" % (self.name)

class Person(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    role = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    is_person_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, index=True)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    comments = db.Column(db.String(255))
    animals = db.relationship('Animal', secondary='permissions', backref='persons', lazy = 'dynamic'))

    @property
    def password(self):
        """
        Prevent password from being accessed
        """
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute.')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        """
        Set password to a hashed password
        """
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        """
        Check if hashed password matches actual password
        """
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Person name='%s', '%s', '%s')" % (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.username)


# Set up user_loader
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Person.query.get(int(user_id))
```

And here is the view:

```
# app/auth/views.py

from flask import flash, redirect, render_template, url_for
from flask_login import login_required, login_user, logout_user

from . import auth
from .forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm
from .. import db
from ..models import Person, Facility

@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    """
    Handle requests to the /register route
    Add a person to the database through the registration form
    """
    form = RegistrationForm()
    form.facility_id.choices = [(f.id, f.name) for f in Facility.query.order_by('name')]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        person = Person(facility=form.facility_id.data,
                            email=form.email.data,
                            username=form.username.data,
                            first_name=form.first_name.data,
                            last_name=form.last_name.data,
                            password=form.password.data)

        # add person to the database
        db.session.add(person)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('You have successfully registered! You may now login.')

        # redirect to the login page
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

    # load registration template
    return render_template('auth/register.html', form=form, title='Register')
```

Comment: you have stated this is many-to-many but the line `facility = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('facilities.id'))` suggests otherwise. Each person is associated with precisely one `Facility`. That is a start to discovering why this is not working...

Comment: Thanks Attack68, I fixed that problem.  I thought it was odd that after removing facility_id from the Person model, when I did 'db flask migrate,' there were no changes detected.   Anyway, the original problem is still there; no rows are being inserted into association table 'workers.'

Comment: A few questions @CharleyM Why don't you have a model class created for Workers? are you just thinking that it would have no useful info/behavior beyond linking person to facility? I'm not sure if this is best practices or out of date, but I found this example that does create model class for the 2 entities as well as the manymany table. https://www.michaelcho.me/article/many-to-many-relationships-in-sqlalchemy-models-flask another thing it does differently than you...

Comment: is that they refer from each model to the other through the intermediate model. I wonder if for starters you might add `facilities` or `work_sites` or similar to Person. then in your person creation form you can have like checkboxes or some other multiselect to indicate to which facilities the new person should be connected. your register function would have to be updated to set that new field on person from the form data

Comment: @Michael, Yes, I'm thinking that the only purpose of the workers table is to store the many to many links; I don't think I need any extra info or functionality in that association table.  I looked at the article you linked to; it's close, but in his case the 'orders' table does more.  I don't have a 'facilities' column in my persons model because I thought that the ```    persons = db.relationship('Person', secondary='workers', backref='facilities', lazy = 'dynamic')
``` statement in my facilities model caused the facilities column to be created in persons through the 'backref' assignment?...

Comment: as seen in [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) and search for 'When using the backref parameter instead of ' to see where class Child has no explicit column for parents; it's added by the backref in parents (I think?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the support @Michael.  You were close enough that I found the problem; it was that I was not adding the person to the persons collection for the facility, so no row was inserted into the workers table.  I added

```
        facility = Facility.query.filter_by(id=form.facility_id.data).first()
        facility.persons.append(person)
        db.session.commit()
```

after the existing code

```
        db.session.add(person)
        db.session.commit()
```

in the registration view and it is correctly inserting rows in the workers table now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/25669256/1449799 ? It seems that the issue you're having is that in your `register()` function, there's no mention of facilities.

Without changing your model classes (e.g. to have the Person model know about its connected facilities in addition to the reverse of what you do have now in Facility for Person), I think you may be able to do something in register() like:

```py
#this should maybe come after db.session.add(person), but before db.session.commit()
selected_facility = Facility.query.get(form.facility_id.data)
selected_facility.persons.append(person)
```

or alternatively

```py
#this should maybe come after db.session.add(person), but before db.session.commit()
selected_facility = Facility.query.get(form.facility_id.data)
person.facilities.append(selected_facility)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100671/1449799 doesn't work, I wonder if it's as simple as a spelling issue? You've said that the back ref from Facility to Person should be called `facilities`. perhaps in your call to the `Person` constructor in your `register` function you should change:

```
person = Person(facility=form.facility_id.data,
```

to

```
person = Person(facilities=[form.facility_id.data],
```

Comment: @Midhael I tried that; the app runs but when I submit a new registration, it gives me  'TypeError: Incompatible collection type: int is not list-like' because the form is returning the integer facility ID of the chosen facility, and facilities is (I think?) a collection that results from an SQL query on the workers table.  SQLAlchemy composes that query (I think?) based on the backref.