# Many-to-many relation insert record in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

With **marshmallow@3.11.1**, **Flask@1.1.2**, **Flask-SQLAlchemy@2.4.4** and S**QLAlchemy@1.3.23** I am trying to store a new data in DB.

I do not have any issues creating records without any relations on with one-to-many relations, but I am struggling to create a new record with a many-to-many relations.

I have *Positions*, which may have different *Types*. To have a many-to-many relation I use an associated table:

```
class PositionsModel(db.Model):

  __tablename__ = "positions"

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  position_name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)

  types_of_work = db.relationship(
    "TypesOfWorkModel",
    secondary=positions_types_of_work,
    lazy="joined",
    backref=db.backref("type_positions", lazy="noload")
  )

def __init__(self, data):
    self.position_name = data.get("position_name")
    self.types_of_work = data.get("types_of_work", [])
  
  def create(self):
    db.session.add(self)
    db.session.commit()

class TypesOfWorkModel(db.Model):

  __tablename__ = "types_of_work"

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  work_type_name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)


positions_types_of_work = db.Table(
  "positions_types_of_work",
  db.Column("position_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("positions.id"), primary_key=True),
  db.Column("type_of_work_id", db.Integer, 
            db.ForeignKey("types_of_work.id"), primary_key=True)
)
```

I also have a schema for every other table, which I am using when creating records. Here is my schema for creating a new Position:

```
class PositionsModelSchemaCreate(Schema):

  id = fields.Int()
  position_name = fields.Str(required=True)
  types_of_work = fields.List(
    fields.Int,
    validate=validate_types_of_work
  )

  @post_load
  def attach_models(self, data, **kwargs):
    # query to get actual model records for "types_of_work"
    return data
```

So what happens when a request comes to create a new position?

```
  """
    request data looks like this:
    {
      "position_name": "Test",
      "types_of_work": [1, 2]
    }
  """
  req_data = request.get_json()
  data = positions_schema_create.load(req_data)
```

This piece of code loads data according to the schema, calls validation functions. In *types_of_work* case it just checks in the IDs in the request body are the IDs of the existing records in the DB.

Then it reaches @*post_load* decorator, which substitutes the IDs for *types_of_work* to actual DB records of those types.

Eventually, my request data will look like this:

```
{
  'position_name': 'Pos Name Test',
  'types_of_work': [<TypesOfWork One>, <TypesOfWork Two>]
}
```

Which I am using for creation:

```
  position = PositionsModel(data)
  position.create()
```

And it returns me an error:

`int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TypesOfWorkModel'`

I read a few other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668092/flask-sqlalchemy-many-to-many-insert-data) and [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/sql/many+to+many+relationship+in+flask+sqlalchemy) and looks like I am doing everything accordingly, but still have an error.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have `, primary_key=True` in your association table, I don't think that's required and it's in neither of the examples you shared

Comment: @RolvApneseth Hmm, yeah, you're right, removed that, but same error is still there

Comment: Yeah I figured it wouldn't, I've up voted your question anyway hopefully someone who knows more about this can help out

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
position = PositionsModel(**data)
position.create()
```

if in @post_load return json/dict