# how to insert data into many-to-many relations using SQLAlchemy? Error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, psycopg2

I am trying to insert this data

```
[{
    "name": "CORVETTE",
    "officers": [{"first_name": "Alan1", "rank": "Commander"}, 
             {"first_name": "Alan2", "rank": "Soldier"}]
  },
  {
    "name": "CRUISER",
    "officers": [{"first_name": "Alan1", "rank": "Commander"}, 
             {"first_name": "Alan3", "rank": "Soldier"}]
  }
]
```

in Postgres db into the many-to-many SQLAlchemy relationship

```
class Officer_orm(Base):
    __tablename__ = "officer_orm"
    first_name = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)
    rank = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)

    spaceships_orm = relationship('Spaceship_orm', 
                      secondary='spaceships_officers', 
                      lazy='subquery', 
                      back_populates='officers_orm')


class Spaceship_orm(Base):
    __tablename__ = "spaceship_orm"
    name = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)

    officers_orm = relationship('Officer_orm', 
                    secondary='spaceships_officers', 
                    lazy='subquery', 
                    back_populates='spaceships_orm')            


class SpaceshipsOfficers(Base):
    __tablename__ = "spaceships_officers"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    o_first_name = Column(String(255))
    o_rank = Column(String(255))
    s_name = Column(String(255), ForeignKey('spaceship_orm.name'))
    __table_args__ = ((ForeignKeyConstraint(["o_first_name", "o_rank"], 
                          ["officer_orm.first_name","officer_orm.rank"])),) 

# .... fill spaceships from json
for s in json_spaceships:
    # .... fill spaceships.officers from json
    with Session(engine) as session:
        spaceship_orm = Spaceship_orm(name=s.name)
        for o in officers:
            officer_orm = Officer_orm(first_name=o.first_name, rank=o.rank)
            spaceship_orm.officers_orm.append(officer_orm)

        session.add_all([spaceship_orm])
        session.commit()
```

but when inserting the second spaceship CRUISER I get an error
`ERROR:root:(psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "officer_orm_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (first_name,rank)=(Alan1, Commander) already exists.`
because Alan1 object was successfully inserted into the "officer_orm" table during the first CORVETTE spaceship insertion

Could you please help me to avoid this error and insert all the relations correctly

| id | o_first_name | o_rank | s_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alan1 | Commander | CORVETTE |
| 2 | Alan2 | Soldier | CORVETTE |
| 3 | Alan1 | Commander | CRUISER |
| 4 | Alan3 | Soldier | CRUISER |

I experimented with `lazy='subquery'` ([Flask sqlalchemy many-to-many insert data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668092/flask-sqlalchemy-many-to-many-insert-data)) and commit order, but it didn't help

Comment: What is the relationship that you are trying to model? An officer can be on many ships, and a ship can have many officers?

Comment: Yes, one officer can be part of the crew of several spaceships.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with check if officer has been already inserted before new `session.add(officer_orm)`

```
with Session(engine) as session:
        spaceship_orm = Spaceship_orm(name=s.name)
        session.add(spaceship_orm)
        session.commit()

        for o in officers:
            officer_orm = Officer_orm(first_name=o.first_name, rank=o.rank)
            spaceship_orm.officers_orm.append(officer_orm)

            existed_officer = session.query(Officer_orm).filter(Officer_orm.first_name==o.first_name,
                                                                Officer_orm.rank==of.rank,
                                                                ).all()
            if len(existed_officer) == 0:
                officer_orm = Officer_orm(first_name=o.first_name, rank=o.rank)
                session.add(officer_orm)
                session.commit()
            else:
                officer_orm = existed_officer[0]
                    
            spaceship_orm.officers_orm.append(officer_orm)
            session.commit()
```